# Student Shell - cd not working

Tags: linux, shell, exec, fork, cd

I'm working on a simple Linux Shell, it can fork() and call execvp(), but I recently added "build in functions" which need to NOT fork().

Here is the execution handling:

```
    if (strcmp(cmd, "exit") == 0) {
        exit = 1;
    }
    else if (builtIn(opt) == 0){
        execvp(cmd, opt);
    }
    else {
        pid_t pID = fork();

        if (pID == 0) { 
            execvp(cmd, opt);
        } else if (pID < 0) { 
            printf("\nFailed to fork\n");
        } else {
            wait(0);
        }
    }
```

builtIn() just checks the command and returns 1 or 0:

```
int builtIn(char * opt[]) {

    if (strcmp(opt[0], "cd")) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is the exit check looking at `cmd` while the built in check looking at `opt[0]`? Looks like you should be checking `cmd` for `cd` not `opt[0]`.

Comment: What is your question? What exactly is the code doing, and how does that differ from your expectation?

Comment: sorry, my code is a mess, cmd is leftover from when I didn't know the command is stored as the first element of the options array passed to execvp().  Commands are working (ls, cal, etc), but not cd.  cd does nothing, and I had hoped not forking would resolve this issue.

Comment: @Will I think you are getting confused about the difference between a command and a process. Things like ls and cal are processes; things that do something and terminate (hopefully). Things like exit and cd are commands, they change the state of the shell (or kill it). Just as you dont call exec on exit, you dont exec on cd. You have to implement the change of state of switching working directories when the command is cd within the shell itself. Note, if you try `which cd` or `which exit` in a shell, it cannot be found, which `which ls` and `which cat` are in your path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that you need to avoid forking, but you also need to avoid executing. There is no `/bin/cd` that programs call to change directories.

Instead of executing something, call the `chdir` system call with your path. If the user types `cd /tmp`, call `chdir("/tmp")`

The **current directory** is a *property of each process* (as the open files or the umask value)  You cannot call a program to change your current dir, as a program *is a different process* and will change effectively its directory (not yours).  That's the reason of not existing a cd external command and to have to make a system call to change it.

Comment: I would call [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) a *system call*, not a library function (even if technically it is a thin wrapper to a syscall)

Comment: Thanks, I asked a professor and chdir doesn't seem too hard to add.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Luis answer. Even if there is a program cd in /bin, it won't work since each process have their own pwd(present working directory) so it changes pwd of the cd program not its parent, main shell.